# Reshaping vector with indices in python

Tags: python, sorting, vector, indexing

I am having some problems resizing a list in python. I have a vector (A) with -9999999 as a few of the elements. I want to find those elements remove them and remove the corresponding elements in B.

I have tried to index the non -9999999 values like this:

```
i = [i for i in range(len(press)) if press[i] !=-9999999]
```

But I get an error when I try to use the index to reshape press and my other vector.
Type Error: list indices must be integers, not list

The vectors have a length of about 26000

Basically if I have vector A I want to remove -9999999 elements from A and 65 and 32 in B.

```
A = [33,55,-9999999,44,78,22,-9999999,10,34]
B = [22,33,65,87,43,87,32,77,99]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [33,55,-9999999,44,78,22,-9999999,10,34]
B = [22,33,65,87,43,87,32,77,99]
A1, B1 = (list(x) for x in zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B) if a != -9999999)))
print(A1)
print(B1)
```

This yields:

```
[33, 55, 44, 78, 22, 10, 34]
[22, 33, 87, 43, 87, 77, 99]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `vector`, so I think you're looking for a `NumPy` based solution:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(A)
>>> b = np.array(B)
>>> b[a!=-9999999]
array([22, 33, 87, 43, 87, 77, 99])
```

Pure Python solution using [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(B, (x != -9999999 for x in A)))
[22, 33, 87, 43, 87, 77, 99]
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> A = [33,55,-9999999,44,78,22,-9999999,10,34]*10000
>>> B = [22,33,65,87,43,87,32,77,99]*10000
>>> a = np.array(A)
>>> b = np.array(B)
>>> %timeit b[a!=-9999999]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(compress(B, (x != -9999999 for x in A)))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think you don't need the `np.where` call (+1)

Comment: I don't think you need numpy at all for this task

Comment: @justinls You don't need it, but with 26000 elements, it's going to be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [j for i, j in zip(A, B) if i != -9999999]
```

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) merges two lists, creating a list of the pairs (x, y). Using list comprehension you can filter the elements that are -999999 in A.